# Xamarin iOS: How to open a .pdf file using the default reader?

Tags: c#, ios, pdf, xamarin, assets

I'm using Xamarin iOS. I'd like to have our application open a .pdf file in the default reader. For Android I managed to get it done by following a two-fold process: (1) copy the file from the Assets folder to the Android device's Downloads folder, and (2) starting an activity to view the file.

I cannot find any similar resources for the iOS. We don't want to use the control in the Xamarin [website,](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/) as it involves downloading lots of JavaScript (?) code, making the size of the app bigger, and also doesn't support pinching the screen to zoom. We want to use the OS's default pdf reader.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Set the Build Action to BundleResource. You can set the build action for a file by right-clicking on that file and and choosing Build Action in the menu that opens.
Create a UIWebView and add it to a view:

```
webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
View.AddSubview(webView);
```

Load the file using NSUrl and NSUrlRequest classes:

```
string fileName = "Loading a Web Page.pdf"; // remember case-sensitive
string localDocUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

**Method 2:**

```
public void OpenFile (NSUrl fileUrl)
{
    var docControl = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl (fileUrl);

    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var subViews = window.Subviews;
    var lastView = subViews.Last ();
    var frame = lastView.Frame;

    docControl.PresentOpenInMenu (frame, lastView, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's not compiling, and is offering three solutions: (1a) Fully qualify 'Webclient with Data.Abstractions.WebClient, (1b) Fully qualify 'Webclient with Plugin.WebClient, (2) Generate type 'WebClient,' and (3) Add reference to 'System.dll..' Which one should I use?

Comment: The previous code only works on shared project, try it now @MrProgrammer

Comment: @MrProgrammer is there some way to scroll webview programmatically ?